# Does value of differentiation as infinity implies continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I come across Mean value theorem proof which is attached below[image]

Which has an assumption that f has derivative (finite or infinite ) at each interior point and continuity is assumed at endpoint.
In proof assumption used that function f is continuous over whole interval.
But I am not convinced with fact that f has infinite derivative and continuous at that point .
I tried to use definition I get $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|f'(c)$ one side is infinite how to show for continuity.

Also Is it possible to have function which every where derivation infinity?
I think question is wrong As I could not imagine function every where like a verticle line.
 But Asking for in case exist?
Any help will be appreciated

Edit:
[image]

[image]

Sorry Everyone As In book already specified definition which already assume continuity of function to define the derivative.

Comment: The theorem statement is certainly problematic.  Taking $f(x)=x^{2/3}$ we have a continuous function with infinite derivative at $x=0$, but there is no solution to $f'(x)=0$ (despite the fact that $f(-1)=f(1)$ and so on).  I expect they meant for the "infinite derivatives" to occur only at the endpoints.

Comment: @lulu Is $f'(0)=+\infty$ or $-\infty$ in your example?

Comment: Apostol, in his definition of infinite derivative, pre-supposes continuity at the point in question.

Comment: How is "has infinite derivative" defined? Does $x\mapsto \operatorname{sgn}(x)$ have ininfite derivative at $0$ because $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(h)-\operatorname{sgn}(0)}{h}=+\infty$ or does the very definition demand more?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  "Vertical tangent" would be a better way to describe it.  And one could argue that the assumptions preclude any other sort of singularity...but the proof sketched in the excerpt doesn't appear to address the issue.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Can you provide Apostol's definition?  It seems, from the discussion, that he is using a non-standard definition.  That might well be the source of the confusion.

Comment: You should tell us _exactly_ what Apostol's definition of $f'(x)=+\infty$ is. People have said it's basically something, or the way to describe it is whatever - nobody has stated exactly what the definition says.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Below I'm assuming the usual definition of infinite derivatives, which is to say that $f'(0)=+\infty$ if $\lim_{h\to0}(f(h)-f(0))/h=+\infty$. I've been told that that's not the definition Apostol uses...

In the usual statement of Rolle's theorem we assume that $f$ is *differentiable* on $(a,b)$, which is to say it has a finite derivative.

You're right, the existence of an infinite derivative at a point does not imply continuity. And in fact a simple counterexample for that is also a counterexample to the theorem as  stated: Define $f:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R$ by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1-x,&(0<x\le 1),
\\0,&(x=0),
\\-1-x,&(-1\le x<0).\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ satisfies all the hypotheses but there is no $x$ with $f'(x)=0$.

And of course it's easy to see where the proof fails: $f$ does not assume a max or min in $(-1,1)$.

What book did you find this nonsense in?

Note the theorem, *with* the usual definition of the derivative as above, becomes correct if we *assume* that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Tom Apostol's Mathematical Analysis Sir...

Comment: According to Apostol's definition, this function does not have $f'(0)=\infty$. Apostol's treatment, while eccentric, is sound.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ok,  what's Aposol's definition? The example I gave _does_ satisfy $\lim_{h\to0}(f(h)-f(0))/h = +\infty$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Basically it must be continuous before it can has an infinite derivative: the graph has a vertical tangent.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown "Basically" schmasically. What's the _definition_?

Comment: I have checked my copy of Apostol's Mathematical Analysis (spanish translation). Definition 5-6 includes the condition of continuity at $x_0$ to define lateral derivatives, possibly $\pm\infty$, at $x_0$.

Comment: Thanks David. This function $f$ is an example wich have infinity derivative but is not continuous in the point, 0 in the case. In the Apostol's book sugeres that existence infinite of derivative garantes continuity in the point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Apostol requires continuity at the points where the derivative becomes infinity. At all the other points, the derivative is a real number, and hence the function is continuous there. It follows that your function is continuous everywhere.